# Vectorising Date Array Calculations

Tags: matlab, date

I simply want to generate a series of dates 1 year apart from today.

I tried this

```
CurveLength=30;
t=zeros(CurveLength);

t(1)=datestr(today);

x=2:CurveLength-1;
t=addtodate(t(1),x,'year');
```

I am getting two errors so far?

???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
Which I am guessing is related to the fact that the date is a string, but when I modified the string to be the same length as the date dd-mmm-yyyy i.e. 11 letters I still get the same error.

Lsstly I get the error

??? Error using ==> addtodate at 45
Quantity must be a numeric scalar.

Which seems to suggest that the function can't be vectorised? If this is true is there anyway to tell in advance which functions can be vectorised and which can not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add `n` years to a date `x`, you do this:

```
y = addtodate(x, n, 'year');
```

However, [`addtodate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addtodate.html) requires the following:

1. `x` must be a scalar number, not a string.
2. `n` must be a scalar number, not a vector.

Hence the errors you get.

I suggest you use a loop to do this:

```
CurveLength = 30;
t = zeros(CurveLength, 1);
t(1) = today; % # Whatever today equals to...
for ii = 2:CurveLength
    t(ii) = addtodate(t(1), ii - 1, 'year');
end
```

Now that you have all your date values, you can convert it to strings with:

```
datestr(t);
```

And here's a neat one-liner using [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addtodate.html);

```
datestr(arrayfun(@(n)addtodate(today, n, 'year'), 0:CurveLength))
```

Comment: @user1884905 Yes, I also wanted to mention that, but then I thought that maybe `today` is maybe a specific time point regardless of the current time, for instance 12:00AM.

Comment: Fair enough. (Now it's there in a comment anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're sequence has a constant known start, you can use datenum in the following way:

```
t = datenum( startYear:endYear, 1, 1)
```

This works fine also with months, days, hours etc. as long as the sequence doesn't run into negative numbers (like 1:-1:-10). Then months and days behave in a non-standard way.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution without a loop (possibly faster):

```
CurveLength=30;
t=datevec(repmat(now(),CurveLength,1));
x=[0:CurveLength-1]';
t(:,1)=t(:,1)+x;
t=datestr(t)
```

datevec splits the date into six columns [year, month, day, hour, min, sec]. So if you want to change e.g. the year you can just add or subtract from it.

If you want to change the month just add to t(:,2). You can even add numbers > 12 to the month and it will increase the year and month correctly if you transfer it back to a datenum or datestr.